# Flink sql : how to find the size of json array

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am using flink sql to read data from kafka. One field in kafka message is array, example

```
{
  "description": "som description",
  "owner": {
    "type": "some",
    "id": "5ff4eb4fed9b4b1288d7993944a8ca23"
  },
  "someArray": [
    {
      "type": "foo",
      "id": "c31a2d10134146e29726fb87246b68d0"
    },
    {
      "type": "foo1",
      "id": "c31a2d10134146e29726fb87246b68d0"
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to write a select statement similar to
`select description, size_of(someArray) from some_table;`

Flink does NOT have `size_of` function. Can I get the length of `someArray` which is `2` in this example, using some built-in functions ?

I have tried to write an UDF for this, challenge i have with udf is when the query are executed with sql-gateway i get class not found exception on the UDF class ( its a java class ).
When i try the same with cli `sql-client` i can get the udf to work.
I have added the jar that contains the udf to `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-flink/1.16.0/libexec/lib` when running it on my machine

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in system function `CARDINALITY` to get the length of an array like so:

```
select cardinality(someArray) as array_length...;
```

For more information about collection functions in the table API, please check the [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/table/functions/systemfunctions/#collection-functions).

Comment: I tried this 
`select CARDINALITY(json_array('[1,2,3]'));`
`select CARDINALITY('[1,2,3]')`

CARDINALITY does not table varchar, it needs multiset. I get this error
`org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Cannot apply 'CARDINALITY' to arguments of type 'CARDINALITY(<VARCHAR(2147483647)>)'. Supported form(s): 'CARDINALITY(<MULTISET>)'`